# Wp eCommerce - Staying within category when product tag is clicked.

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

I have categories set up in WP eCommerce and I also have product tags set up as well. But let's say I'm in the t-shirt category then I click the product tag "blue". I would like it to stay within the t-shirt category instead of showing all products in the whole store. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this creating separate custom navs out of the product tags then using isotope to handle the filtering of products. It was actually easier than I thought. Just figured I would post my resolution just incase someone ran across this question.